# Android Gmail App fails to attach my CSV file

Tags: java, android

The following code works when I attach my csv file to the default email application on android, but does not work when I attach that same file to the gmail application.  Does anyone have a solution for the gmail problem?

```
Resources res = getResources();         
        FileOutputStream outPut;

        try {
            outPut = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("IPAddressPlanner.csv", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

            SendMail.createCSVAttachment(outPut, res, values_subnet, values_mask, values_inverse, values_subnet_size, values_host_range, values_broadcast);

            File F = getApplicationContext().getFileStreamPath("IPAddressPlanner.csv");
            Uri U = Uri.fromFile(F);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("message/rfc822"); // use from live device
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "IPV4 Address Information");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, U);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Select email application."));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: No one has encountered this issue really?  I find that the file attaches to the gmail app but when it is actually sent, I find no file attachment in my own gmail account.